# How to instantiate concrete successor with forms

Tags: php, symfony

I have a class which has relationship with some abstract entity. When I want to create controller for creating this abstract entity (concrete successor instance, of course) - I have no idea how to define which class would be instantiated in FormType without manually overriding it (and creating several controllers, one for each concrete successor class.

The only idea I have - is to implement registry, which would store all possible successor classes (automatically collected via services and tags) and select a concrete class from this registry, providing form choice to choose.

But maybe there is more clever way?

```
class Foo
{
    /** @var AbstractBase[] */
    public $children;
}

abstract class AbstractBase
{
    public $foo;
}

class ConcreteBase1 extends AbstractBase
{
    public $bar;
}

class ConcreteBase2 extends AbstractBase
{
    public $baz;
}

//..Controller...//

/** 
 * @Template()
 * @Route("/some/path", name="entity_create")
 */
public function createAction(Request $request)
{
    $builder = $this->createFormBuilder()
       ->add('type', 'choice', array(
           'choices' => $this->get('base_successor_registry')->all()
         ))
       ->add('submit', 'submit');

    $form = $builder->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid())
    {
         // Of cource the should implement also some DataTransformers here or some kind of class choosing stuff
         $conreteEntity = $form->getData();
         $this->getDoctrine()->persist($conreteEntity);
         $this->getDoctrine()->flush();

         return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('entity_edit',array('entity'=>$entity)));
    }

    return array('form'=>$form->createView());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've end up with following configuration as most convinient:

- Each entity type SHOULD be declared to be a service with some kind of `identifier` to list possible types to create (just sluggify class name is possible like `\Some\Package\Class` goes to `some_package_class`) and SHOULD be stored in some kind of registry
- Each entity type MAY implement some kind of `FormAwareEntityInterface` which returns `FormTypeInterface` for given class
- Abstract entity MAY be implemented to bootstrap Doctrine inheritance and sample FormType
- Concrete creator controller SHOULD use entity type identifier to obtain `$object` from registry
- Concrete creator controller SHOULD forcibly pass `get_class($object)` as form's `data_class` option or use `FormAwareEntityInterface` features to determine form options
- Concrete creator controller SHOULD forcibly pass only a `clone $object` to form creator
- Editor controller SHOULD use forcibly pass `get_class($object)` as form's `data_class` option or use `FormAwareEntityInterface` features to determine form options

Some code snippets

```
interface FormAwareEntityInterface
{
    /** @return FormTypeInterface */
    public function getFormType();
}


/**
 * @Template()
 * @Route("/types", name="admin_list_types")
 */
public function listTypesAction()
{
    return array('types' => $this->get('some_entity_registry')->all());
}


/**
 * @Template()
 * @Route("/create/{type}", name="admin_create_typed_instance")
 * @param Request $request
 * @param         $type
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function createAction(Request $request, $type)
{
    if (!$this->get('some_entity_registry')->has($type)) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException("Type $type is not registered as entity type");
    }

    $entity = $this->get('some_entity_registry')->get($type);

    if ($entity instanceof FormAwareEntityInterface) {
        $formType = $entity->getFormType();
        $form     = $this->createForm($formType, clone $entity, array('data_class' => get_class($entity)));
    } else {
        $form = $this->createFormBuilder(clone $entity, array('data_class' => get_class($entity)))->getForm();
    }

    $form->add('submit', 'submit');

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $entity = $form->getData();

        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->persist($entity);
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('admin_edit_instance', array('entity' => $entity->getId()));
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView(), 'entity' => $this->get('some_entity_registry')->get($type));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since form types already indeded to be registerd as services, I end up with Idea not to tag classes, but `FormType`s which implement forms for them. The code will look like following

The cons of this idea is that editing entity is not trivial. When I fetch entity from repository, I should decide, which form_type is used to edit this. I am thinking of two approaches

1. Add static `getFormType()` method to each class to return default form type to edit entity class
2. Update the registry to make it capable of deciding, which form type to use (since each form type should have `data_class` option set)

**This is still not last answer and I'm looking if there is more correct way.**

**UPD. This way makes me to implement form type even for those successors, which do not have any special configuration (just logic differences)**

services.yml:

```
form_type.concrete_base_1:
   class: Foo\Bar\ConcreteBase1
   tags:
   - { name: form.type, alias: concrete_base_1 }
   - { name: base_form_type }

  form_type.concrete_base_2:
   class: Foo\Bar\ConcreteBase2
   tags:
   - { name: form.type, alias: concrete_base_2 }
   - { name: base_form_type }
```

Compiler pass to collect FormTypes

```
class BaseFormTypesRegistryPass implements CompilerPassInterface {
    /**
     * You can modify the container here before it is dumped to PHP code.
     *
     * @param ContainerBuilder $container
     *
     * @api
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition('base_form_types_registry')) {
            return;
        }

        $definition = $container->getDefinition('base_form_types_registry');

        $menuServices = $container->findTaggedServiceIds('base_form_type');

        foreach ($menuServices as $id => $tagAttributes) {
            foreach ($tagAttributes as $attributes) {
                $definition->addMethodCall(
                    'add',
                    array(new Reference($id))
                );
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Sample controller

```
class BaseController extends Controller 
{

    /** 
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/entity/create", name="entity_create")
     * This controller renders a list with all possible sucessors
     */
    public function createAction()
    {
        return array('types'=> $this->get('base_form_types_registry')->all());
    }

    /** 
     * @Template()
     * @Route("/some/path/{type}", name="entity_create_conrete")
     */
    public function createConreteAction(Request $request, $type)
    {
        if (!$this->get('base_form_types_registry')->has($type)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException('Invalid form type selected');
        }

        $form = $this->createForm($type)
           ->add('submit', 'submit');

        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isValid())
        {
             $conreteEntity = $form->getData();
             $this->getDoctrine()->persist($conreteEntity);
             $this->getDoctrine()->flush();

             return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('entity_edit',array('entity'=>$entity)));
        }

        return array('form'=>$form->createView());
    }

}
```